# How to include Room persistence library in java-library?

Tags: android, module, android-room, androidx, clean-architecture

I have three modules

app module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
//..
```

domain module

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
}
//..
```

data module

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}
//..
```

i am trying to add room library in data module

```
//..
java {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
implementation project(path: ':domain')

//coroutine
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutine_version"

//room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0.
```

i already have google() inside project module

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

but it keeps telling me that it doesn't recognize room library!

Comment: What is the Gradle version you are using?

Comment: @Anand I am using Gradle version 6.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data Module` should be of type `Android Library` since I am using Room persistence library which can't be used inside java library because it depends on android platform apis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jcenter()` to the repositories block -

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```